# How to: add a blank space after every 4 characters when typing in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a way to add a blank space while typing in a `TextFormField`.

I found a way how to do this a while back but I cannot find it now, no matter what I search for on Google or here on StackOverflow ..

Basically I want to turn the text shown in the textfield from `000011112222333` to `0000 1111 2222 3333`

I'm guessing I need to use some `RegExp` check in the `onChanged` function of a `TextFormField` and use it to change the `TextEditingController`'s `.text`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also faced this problem before and luckily found a way to do this somewhere.
First create a class that extends TextInputFormatter

customInputFormatter.dart

```
class CustomInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var text = newValue.text;

    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }

    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      buffer.write(text[i]);
      var nonZeroIndex = i + 1;
      if (nonZeroIndex % 4 == 0 && nonZeroIndex != text.length) {
        buffer.write(' '); // Replace this with anything you want to put after each 4 numbers
      }
    }

    var string = buffer.toString();
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: string,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: string.length)
    );
  }
}
```

And then add it to the list of inputFormatters[] of TextFormField

```
inputFormatters: [
   FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
   new CustomInputFormatter()
],
```

Comment: Nice one! Will check this out tomorrow but this looks similar to what I found before so sure it will work :D

Comment: Hi mate, I gave this a go but it's formatting the string like this "4444 4  4   4    4    4"  .. I also can't seem to create the FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly ... is that necessary?

Comment: Can you post the code of how you implemented it? The FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly is to ensure that you can only enter number (digits). This is because I think you want to implement this for credit card

Comment: I created a class using the exact code you have above and added a parameter for my custom TextFormField widget that takes a List<TextInputFormatter> ... Then I've simply added the CustomInputFormatter in the way you have above

Comment: I've created a [pen](https://codepen.io/dungngo96/pen/ZEOxKBV). You can check and follow

Comment: I'm unable to use the FilteringTextInputFormatter, I think my version of Flutter might be older than yours .. I've just ran this project and the same thing is happening. Can you remove the FilteringTextInputFormatter and see if you get the desired result? https://ibb.co/4PWQMmM

Comment: yeah, it throw an error if FilteringTextInputFormetter is omitted. This is on codepen though, so I don't really know the version. You might want to upgrade your flutter version

Comment: maybe try WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly instead if you are on older version, since WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is deprecated and replaced by FilteringTextInputFormetter

Comment: Perfect! That solved the problem! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Cursor is jumping and adding unnecessary spaces when i used this solution

Comment: Like being enlightened, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Inspired from Dung Ngo's Code

I added cursor tracking so when the user erases from the the TextFormField the cursor doesn't goes back to the beginning of field.

I commented the WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly / FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly in my pen since I used regular expressions.

Here's the pen https://codepen.io/brocatz/pen/dyNOqVy

```
@override
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var text = newValue.text;
    text = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(\s)|(\D)'), '');

    int offset = newValue.selection.start;
    var subText =
        newValue.text.substring(0, offset).replaceAll(RegExp(r'(\s)|(\D)'), '');
    int realTrimOffset = subText.length;

    // if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
    //   return newValue;
    // }

    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      buffer.write(text[i]);
      var nonZeroIndex = i + 1;
      if (nonZeroIndex % 4 == 0 && nonZeroIndex != text.length) {
        buffer.write(
            ' '); // Replace this with anything you want to put after each 4 numbers
      }


      if (nonZeroIndex % 4 == 0 &&
          subText.length == nonZeroIndex &&
          nonZeroIndex > 4) {
        int moveCursorToRigth = nonZeroIndex ~/ 4 - 1;
        realTrimOffset += moveCursorToRigth;
      }

      if (nonZeroIndex % 4 != 0 && subText.length == nonZeroIndex) {
        int moveCursorToRigth = nonZeroIndex ~/ 4;
        realTrimOffset += moveCursorToRigth;
      }
    }

    var string = buffer.toString();
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: string,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: realTrimOffset));
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution gives the following error:
W/TextInputPlugin(10676): Changing the content within the the composing region may cause the input method to behave strangely, and is therefore discouraged. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78827 for more details

which results in Strange behavior.
For Example if you switch from Alphabetic to numeric Keyboard, after each Space the Keyboard switches back.

Anyone does have a solution for this?

Comment: This is an improvement of the original answer and is even better. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12),
            TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
              String left = oldValue.text.substring(
                  0, min(oldValue.selection.start, newValue.selection.end));
              String right =
                  oldValue.text.substring(oldValue.selection.end);
              String inserted = newValue.text
                  .substring(left.length, newValue.selection.end);
              String modLeft = left.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), "");
              String modRight = right.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), "");
              String modInserted = inserted.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), "");
              final regEx = RegExp(r'\d{1,4}');
              String processString = modLeft + modInserted + modRight;
              String updated = regEx
                  .allMatches(processString)
                  .map((e) => e.group(0))
                  .join(" ");
              int cursorPosition = regEx
                  .allMatches(modLeft + modInserted)
                  .map((e) => e.group(0))
                  .join(" ")
                  .length;
              return TextEditingValue(
                  text: updated,
                  selection:
                      TextSelection.collapsed(offset: cursorPosition));
            })
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do using a parser as a data processor.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/choice.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/many.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/take_while1.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/take_while_m_n.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    final text = String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(i, (i) => 0x61 + i));
    final newText = convert(text);
    print('$text => $newText');
  }

  const test = ' a bcd   ef  ghi  ';
  final r = convert(test);
  print('$test => $r');
}

String convert(String text) {
  text = text.replaceAll(' ', '');
  const word4 = TakeWhileMN(4, 4, isAnyChar);
  const rest = TakeWhile1(isAnyChar);
  const words = Many(Choice2(word4, rest));
  final r = parseString(words.parse, text);
  return r.join(' ');
}

bool isAnyChar(int c) => true;
```

Output:

```
 =>
a => a
ab => ab
abc => abc
abcd => abcd
abcde => abcd e
abcdef => abcd ef
abcdefg => abcd efg
abcdefgh => abcd efgh
abcdefghi => abcd efgh i
abcdefghij => abcd efgh ij
abcdefghijk => abcd efgh ijk
abcdefghijkl => abcd efgh ijkl
abcdefghijklm => abcd efgh ijkl m
abcdefghijklmn => abcd efgh ijkl mn
abcdefghijklmno => abcd efgh ijkl mno
abcdefghijklmnop => abcd efgh ijkl mnop
abcdefghijklmnopq => abcd efgh ijkl mnop q
abcdefghijklmnopqr => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qr
abcdefghijklmnopqrs => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrst => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst u
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uv
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw => abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvw
 a bcd   ef  ghi   => abcd efgh i
```

Answer (score -2):

in flutter 2.2 you should use `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))` instead of `FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`